# Having issues using the printf()

Tags: java, printf

this is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class two {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("--- Stage 1 Taxi Fare Calculator ---");

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print("Enter in pick up time:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        String startTime = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter in pickup point:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        String pickUp = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter in drop off point:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        String dropOff = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter in trip distance in km:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        Double tripDist = user_input.nextDouble();
        user_input.nextLine();

        Double fareRate = 1.60;
        Double baseFare = tripDist * fareRate;
        Double totalFare = baseFare;

        String m1 = "The pickup point was: %15s%n";
        String m2 = "The drop off point was: %13s%n";
        String m3 = "The pickup time was: %11s%n";
        String m4 = "Estimated distance (km): %12f%n";
        String m5 = "Fare Charged: $%11.2f%n";
        String m6 = "Base fare: $%15.2f%n";
        String m7 = "Total fare: $%14.2f%n";
        String m8 = "Plus surcharges: $%14.2f%n";
        System.out.println(" --- Taxi fare details --- ");
        System.out.printf(m1, pickUp); 
        System.out.printf(m2, dropOff);
        System.out.printf(m3, startTime);
        System.out.printf(m4, tripDist);
        System.out.printf(m5, fareRate);
        System.out.printf(m6, baseFare);
        System.out.printf(m7, totalFare);
    }


}
```

EDIT2 (Final) : I have added more to my code and have now got what you see above, now all i need to do is add surcharges so when its a certain time its a certain cost and also a surcharge for area, anyway not asking for help there just letting you guys know that you have helped out alot and I thank you. BTW I do apologize if I shouldn't be editing this as much as I have.

Comment: Just a note, called `user_input.nextLine();` after your `nextDouble()`, otherwise you'll pull a blank input.

Comment: You should add a `Double fareRate = 0.35;` or prompt the user for the rate (why not use the primitive type `double`?), then `Double fare = trip_dist * fareRate;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be shorter if you declared your variables on the same line you read them and you should `flush()` if you don't `println()`, that is

```
System.out.print("Enter in pick up time:  ");
System.out.flush();
String startTime = user_input.next();

System.out.print("Enter in pickup point:  ");
System.out.flush();
String pickUp = user_input.next();

System.out.print("Enter in drop off point:  ");
System.out.flush();
String dropOff = user_input.next();

System.out.print("Enter in trip distance in km:  ");
System.out.flush();
Double tripDist = user_input.nextDouble();
user_input.nextLine();
```

Then, you need to include the output type in your format `String`(s),

```
String m1 = "The pickup point was: %s%n"; // %n or \n - both are newline
String m2 = "The drop off point was: %s%n";
String m3 = "The pickup time was: %s%n";
String m4 = "Estimated distance (km): %f%n";
String m5 = "Fare Charged: $%.2f%n";
String m6 = "Base fare: $%.2f%n";
String m7 = "Total fare: $%.2f%n";
```

Next, when you call `printf()` you should pass the arguments, not concatenate -

```
System.out.printf(m1, pickUp);
System.out.printf(m2, dropOff);
System.out.printf(m3, startTime);
System.out.printf(m4, tripDist);
System.out.printf(m5, fareRate);
System.out.printf(m6, baseFare);
System.out.printf(m7, totalFare);
```

And then I think it will work as you expect.

Comment: ah you are awesome, Thank you very much. everyone here has been really helpful :D